# Display subject based on status of user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

Hi everyone i have a question how can i display the subject based on the user status. if the user is active which means the the full subject will be displayed but if he is not active i only want to display specific subject.

```
 public function inquirySubject()
    {
       if(auth()->user()->status === 'approved' || auth()->user()->status === 'active')
         {
            $subject = [
            'Inquiry',
            'Follow Up',
            'Technical Problem',
            'Other Application Concern',
            'Payment Concern' ,
            'Proof of Payment'
        ];
        }else{
            $subject = [
            'Inquiry',
            'Follow Up',
            'Technical Problem',
            'Other Application Concern',
            // 'Payment Concern' , // if user is not active or approved this subject line should not     display 
            'Proof of Payment'
        ];
        }
        return response()->json($subject);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to save a bit of code duplication:

```php
 public function inquirySubject()
 {
     $isApprovedOrActiveUser = auth()->user()->status === 'approved' || auth()->user()->status === 'active';
        
     $subject = [
         'Inquiry',
         'Follow Up',
         'Technical Problem',
         'Other Application Concern',
         'Proof of Payment'
     ];
 
     if ($isApprovedOrActiveUser) {
        $subject[] = 'Proof of Payment';
     }

     return response()->json($subject);
}
```

You could also implement this logic in a Resource - see: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 0):

Add to model

```
    public const SUBJECT_ACTIVE_OR_APPROVED = [
         'Inquiry',
         'Follow Up',
         'Technical Problem',
         'Other Application Concern',
         'Payment Concern',
         'Proof of Payment',
     ];
```

And

```
public const SUBJECT_NOTACTIVE = [
         'Inquiry',
         'Follow Up',
         'Technical Problem',
         'Other Application Concern',
         'Proof of Payment',
     ];
```

Your function

```
public function inquirySubject()
    {
        return (auth()->user()->status === 'approved' || auth()->user()->status === 'active')
            ? response()->json(Model::SUBJECT_ACTIVE_OR_APPROVED)
            : response()->json(Model::SUBJECT_NOTACTIVE);
    }
```